# Gravitational force between astronomical bodies in a binary system

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, binary-stars

If two celestial bodies of similar mass form a binary system and both have fairly relativistic velocities does in that case gravity act with delay and does the picture shown present the problem in the right way? ...[image]: B is the position of mass 1 and C of mass 2 orbiting in a common orbit since masses are equal. Now, mass at B produces a gravity effect at D which is the point that mass at C will reach due to gravity not being infinitely fast and as the picture shows BD is not perpendicular to the orbit of mass 2. In that case is it legitime ask is that gravitational wave at D causing not only centripetal force but also a force in the direction of motion of the mass 2 when that arrives from C to D?

Comment: The [GR 2 body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem_in_general_relativity) is hard.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for the link...